# How to solve AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewma'?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm facing Attribute error with Pandas Version: 0.24.2

```py
expwighted_avg = pd.ewma(ts_log, halflife=12)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-cbd5d537822b> in <module>()
----> 1 expwighted_avg = pd.ewma(ts_log, halflife=12)

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'ewma'
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ewm.html

Answer (score 1):

For me now it's work and code run successfully

```
    expwighted_avg = ts_log.ewm(halflife=12).mean()
```